# Loadtesting HTTP services

Tags: java, performance, load-testing

We are developing servers that are based on HTTP RESTful APIs, and would like to loadtest the APIs. Could anyone point us to a loadtest that that can do the following:

- Can compose load test scripts by typing and not by clicking any GUI buttons (like jmeter)
- Can compose scenario testing, e.g., say I have two APIs A1 and A2, I will need to call A1 first, then parse the JSON/XML  response result, and then use that result while calling A2
- I am eager to know both commercial and open source options that can attain the above goals

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [soap UI](http://www.soapui.org/)(loadUI).Soap UI comes with inbuilt support of loadUI to automate the testing of webservices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) you'll have the choice to write your scenario in xml files or record them with the built-in recorder.

Comment: how about using Gatling, that seems to be less verbose than XML. Can anyone share their experience using Gatling?